# How do I make slected objects and armatures vanish during certain keyframes?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I'm doing an animation that's going to be used in Unity3D and what I'm trying to do is make certain accessories vanish during these keyframes while still being visible in other keyframes.

For example, if a character was riding a skateboard, the board would be there during the animation but when the character stops or starts walking, the board would vanish.

This is what I want to do with my animation. Because it's part of an upcoming game, I can't share or upload them model or images of it. The object that I'm trying to make invisible for these keyframes also has armature in it.

Any and all advice is greatly appreciated :D

Comment: Just vanish or with some fade effect?

Comment: Could you please provide examples, such as a screenshot, to show how to do this? I still consider myself to be a beginner to Blender.

Comment: The simpler case is to make them vanish instantly. For that, just set the scale from (say) 1 to 0 between two consecutive frames. If some fade in/out effect, I think that can be done easier in Unity playing with a progressive transparency.